# Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {2^n - 1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a closed form for this?$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {2^n - 1}$$

Tried searching but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Have a look at the [Lambert series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertSeries.html).

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n-1}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}2^{-mn} = \sum_{r\geq 1}d(r)\,2^{-r} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28n%3D1%29%5Einf+1%2F%282%5En-1%29) knows it:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2^n-1}=1-\frac{\psi_{\frac12}^{(0)}(1)}{\log 2}=1.606695152415...,
$$
where $\psi_{q} (z)$ is the [$q$-digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html).

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n-1}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2^n-1}=$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}^{(0)}\left(m+1\right)-\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}^{(0)}\left(1\right)}{\ln(2)}=1-\frac{\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}^{(0)}(1)}{\ln(2)}$$